# Can I limit the amount of logging to "/var/log", especially for "bootchart"?

Tags: logging

I've just noticed that I have 342 MB of log files in `/var/log`

In particular `/var/log/bootchart` takes 329 MB of this space!

As I'm only running a home desktop environment, I can't see how I need this amount of "history", and perhaps don't need **bootchart** at all.

How can I limit/prevent this **bootchart** logging (and what purpose does it serve)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, what is bootchart? Bootchart allows you to check the boot sequence and generate a chart showing how long each process ran during the boot process, and how much CPU/IO they used.

Once installed, bootchart runs on every boot. However, you can edit the variable `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT` in '/etc/default/grub' to include `bootchart=disable`, which stops bootchart from running at all. Don't forget to run `sudo update-grub` afterwards to update GRUB's configuration file.

If you want to run it at a later point, edit the GRUB entry at boot (by pressing the 'c' key at the GRUB menu you can edit the highlighted entry), and remove `bootchart=disable` from the the 'linux' line. This will enable bootchart once for the following boot.

Comment: htorque: Thanks... That works nicely... The only thing is that I don't have the "Press C" option at my GRUB menu ...(because I don't have a GRUB menu :) ... but I assume I can just revert via the  GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT variable in '/etc/default/grub'.

Comment: Oh, in that case I don't know if it's not faster to simply install and uninstall bootchart/pybootchartgui everytime you need it. :*) Doesn't BURG or whatever you are using allow you to edit the boot entries?

Comment: I'm using a stock-standard  10.04 install from CD; running on the "metal" (no dual-boot), and pressing "c" feverishly (for two reboots) had no effect.... GRUB is one of those arcane anciliary tools that I indulge in on a "need-to-know only" basis .. It is probably quite simple, but there are lots of other things to learn first :)  ..

Comment: Ah, in that case your boot menu stays hidden. Try to press the left shift key during your next boot and the menu should show up.

Comment: Yes! I just tried **left Shift** on boot; it works; That's a handy bit of info.. Thanks again ;)

Comment: @fred.bear I am surprised no one has asked how to get to the grub menu as it's hidden by default, you should ask that as a separate question!

Comment: @htorque ..  as per Jorge's suggestion, I've just now asked a question specifically about the Grub menu... (you may want to answer it yourself)